# C# winforms / UserControls - How to trigger Event from UserControl1 to UserControl2

Tags: c#, winforms, global-variables

I am trying to trigger a Button1_Click event located in UserControl2 from UserControl1.

Controls are Loaded dynamically from my Main Form

```
//UserControl2
public partial  class ItemsModule : UserControl
{
        private void ButtonRefreshProperties_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RefreshControls();
        }
        public void RefreshControls()
        {
            SomeCode();
        }
}

/// MainForm this is how i add the Control from the Main Form

ItemsModule im = new ItemsModule();
im.Name = "ItemsModule";
flpModules.Controls.Add(im);

//UserControl1
public partial class TreeViewControl :  UserControl
{
    private void ItemTreeView_MouseDoubleClick(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        String ItemId = ItemTreeView.SelectedNode.Name;
        Variables.CurrentItemID = ItemId;
        if (LoadedModules.Items)
        {
            //Here I would like a way to trigger ItemsModule.ButtonRefreshProperties_Click
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Raise an event so that the *form* can call RefreshControls.

Answer (score 2):

`UserControl1` will need to have a references to `UserControl2`.  Once you have a reference `UserControl1` should call a method on `UserControl2` that causes the event to be raised.

You can pass the reference to `UserContro2` in to `UserControl1` via the constructor, a sub, or a property depending on how your application is structured.  You should store the reference in a private field of `UserControl1` so that you can access it from the `DoubleClick` event handler.

It is also possible to set this up in other ways.  You could make `UserControl2` be a property on the parent form, then UserControl1 can cast it's `.Parent` property in to the correct type and use that property as a reference.

You could also set up a 3rd class as a `singleton` that has a reference to `UserControl2`.

The thing that all these solutions have in common is that somehow `UserControl1` needs to have a reference to `UserControl2` to be able to do anything with it.

You could avoid the reference problem by having `UserControl1` raise an event that it's parent form listens for.  Since the parent form should already have a reference to all the controls on it, you can make the form proxy the calls in to `UserControl2` for you.

Comment: unfortunatelly the first solutions won't work. I have added the Reference between the 2 projects (UserControls) throught right click --> Add reference. and i cant make it work

Comment: You are confusing the 2 different uses of "reference" in .net.  I am speaking of a variable reference, not an assembly reference.  For the usage in this answer, consider "reference to..." to be roughly equivalent to "a variable pointing to..."